# Publishing a config file for TCPDF with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, tcpdf

Although I've used TCPDF before I am using it with composer for the first time through Laravel 4.

I am fighting the urge to edit any package files directly but their are config settings/ constants in TCPDF that I would like to be able to change.

I do know vendor config files can be published using:

```
php artisan config:publish {package}
```

But I don't think the TCPDF package I am using has this feature. The package is:

> https://packagist.org/packages/tecnick.com/tcpdf

Don't really know much more about the package either as the git page seems to be down.

So to my questions:

Is publishing the config possible?

If not what would be the best way to to apply custom settings without touching the vendor?

Finally if the above will not really work is their a better **Laravel 4 based solution** that allows for HTML to PDF generation?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to view the source of the package but the publishing of configuration will only work for Laravel specific packages that have setup and registered the package correctly. For other packages that require configuration they should provide some means for extending the configuration to avoid the possibility of adjusted config being overwritten by a `composer update`.

Comment: Thanks for that Jason. I was sort of thinking that but needed it confirming. Do you know of or recommend any PDF generator that works well with Laravel 4?

Comment: I've not had to generate PDFs before. Don't think there is anything specific to Laravel, you'll just have to try them all out. :)

Comment: I added "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "6.0.*" to the "require" part of my composer.json about three months ago and have been generating PDFs from my L4 web app using TCPDF since then - works like a dream.